# textField a mayuscula automaticamente en Java NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

Estoy escribiendo un programa en NetBeans utilizando java, y a la hora de rellenar un **textField** necesito que este se ingrese en mayúscula automáticamente, y lo he logrado con el siguiente código.

```
    private void tfNombreKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if((c<'a'||c>'z')&&(c<'A')|c>'Z')evt.consume();//Solo dejo ingresar letras minúsculas y  mayusculas (no numeros ni caracteres)
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){//Todo lo que ingresa se pone em mayúscula
    String cad=(""+c).toUpperCase();
    c=cad.charAt(0);
    evt.setKeyChar(c);
    }
}
```

Bueno como verán puse un **if** para que solo puedan ingresar caracteres desde la **a** a la **z**. Pero el problema es el siguiente, ***cuando agrego el código para pasar todo mayúscula, no me permite ingresar espacios***. *Pero si ingresa todo en mayúscula.*

Lo que preciso cuando completen el textField, es que solo ingresen letras en minúscula o mayúsculas y la convierta automáticamente en MAYÚSCULA.
***Y por el otro lado es que no puedan ingresar números(12314etc) y tampoco ningún otro símbolo por ejemplo(+'\][])***

***PRECISO poner espacios aplicando el mismo sistema que me pase todo a mayuscula, actualmente escribe todo en mayuscula y no permite otro caracter que solo letras que es lo que preciso, pero no puedo insertar un espacio, por ejemplo: si quiere escribir un nombre CESAR NACHO, no puedo porque no me deja insertar el espacio***

Comment: el espacio es el caracter 32 en ASCII incluyelo en tus condiciones, el 8 en ASCII es el Backspace, deberias incluirlo tambien si quieres borrar lo escrito con la tecla BackSpace o Del

Comment: Hola Japv, y como lo hago en el código? me podrías explicar mas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Character.isLetter(evt.getKeyChar()) || evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE || evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
{
   //Codigo
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es preguntar usando el método `isLetter(char c)` de la clase *Character* (de la cual tú haces uso en tu código) para determinar si el caracter introducido es una letra. Se pregunta también si el caracter es la tecla Espacio o la tecla BackSpace, es decir solo se permitirá hacer algo si se cumple la condición de que el caracter es una letra, un espacio o BackSpace.

La clase *Character* tiene varios métodos, algunos de ellos son:

- `isLetter(char c)`: para saber si el caracter es una letra.
- `isDigit(char c)`: para saber si el caracter es un número.
- `isLetterOrDigit(char c)`: una combinación de los métodos anteriores

Ver: [La clase Character](https://codesitio.com/recursos-utiles-para-tu-web-o-blog/cursos/curso-de-java-la-clase-character/)

Comment: ¿Contempla si la entrada es vía *CTRL + V*?

Comment: Hola Javp, gracias por tu aporte, lo estuve probando, y la verdad que funciona me convierte todo en mayúscula y puedo espaciar y borrar. 
**El problema es que pierdo la función que deseo, que es poder poner solo letras, no permitir el ingreso de números símbolos y puntos**. 
_Sabes como bloquear eso?_ que solo se ingresen palabras de la a a la z y las sean convertidas en mayúscula, y nada de símbolos y números?

Comment: @CesarBarbozaRueda, para eso es la función isLetter(), te lo puse en el código, no entiendo tu duda,

Comment: Hola Japv, que utilizando la linea que me diste, puedo ingresar de todo, {}|}||(*&%$# simbolos que no preciso en dicho campo. La idea es que solo sean letras. O quizas deba anular todo lo anterior que ya tenia?

Comment: @CesarBarbozaRueda, pero claro la idea es que borres tu código anterior y uses este

Comment: Tu código anterior tiene mal la condición if

Comment: @CesarBarbozaRueda, ya resolviste tu problema?

Comment: @Japv no aun no, modifique el post principal asi aclaro mejor. 
Con el codigo que tengo puedo escribir como quiero (solo letras y en mayusuculas) pero no puedo hacer espacio.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias **@Japv** lo solucione tambien utilizando tu metodo. El codigo me quedo asi:

```
    private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) || evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE || evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        //Codigo
        String cad = ("" + c).toUpperCase();
        c = cad.charAt(0);
        evt.setKeyChar(c);
    }
}
```

Tambien es posible usar este codigo para que convierta todo a mayuscula y tome espacios.

```
//minuzcula a MAYUSCULA
char c = evt.getKeyChar();
if ((c < 'a' || c > 'z') && (c < 'A') && (c > 'Z')) {
    evt.consume();//Solo dejo ingresar letras minúsculas y  mayusculas (no numeros ni caracteres)
}//Todo lo que ingresa se pone em mayúscula
String cad = ("" + c).toUpperCase();
c = cad.charAt(0);
evt.setKeyChar(c);
//minuzcula a MAYUSCULA FIN
```

Comment: ¡No olvides alguna de las respuestas! Además, ya no intentes responder a respuestas a través de ediciones.

Comment: Hola padaleiana, gracias por la aclaración. Pasa que lo solucione de dos maneras, de la mía propia con la que cree el post, y también con lo que me aporto Japv

Comment: Olvidé la palabra clave: no olvides _aceptar_ alguna de las respuestas. Sucede que [el usuario "Comunidad" se encarga de revivir las preguntas cada cierto tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215/qu%c3%a9-sucede-con-las-preguntas-que-tienen-respuestas-validas-pero-no-son-marcadas/1452), además de que las preguntas quedan _al aire_ sin respuestas aceptadas.

Comment: Claro te entiendo, pero no me da la opción esa tilde para marcar como respuesta aceptada, es raro. Si vos como moderador la podrías marcar la de Japv te lo agradecería. También me olvide de aclarar en mi respuesta de arriba que mi intensión era aclarar que hay dos formas de lograr lo planteado. La manera de Japv y la mía. Por eso quería que queden los dos códigos, mas que nada para que le sirva a todos aquellos que busquen algo similar.

Comment: Ya veo por qué, ¡tu usuario es distinto! Solicita [combinar tus perfiles de usuario](/contact). Por cierto, todos somos moderadores aquí :)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias padaleiana, ya se funcionaron las cuentas y fue súper rápido y automático. Gracias, también pude marcar la respuesta de Japv como como respuesta correcta. Saludos!!